Can I drop the は in this sentence?

そのためには、たくさんの努力が必要です。

Why did they put a は here?

This question is similar to: は、には、に。。。what is the difference between them?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That is the subject, as the focus is on the reason. You set anything to は if it is relevant to your main point. If we were to be grammatical, if we drop the は, we replace the が with は, as we should always mark a subject to make it clear in context. However, nothing is stopping us from doing this in informal contexts (though it is redundant):

そのためには、たくさんの努力は必要です。

Also:

今日はね、佐藤さんは来ると思ってるけど。

Some は's, like the one attached to 今日, almost become phatic.
To answer your question, we learn to recognize the subject with は, but its exact place can vary.
EDIT: You could drop the は entirely if the subject is made clear in the prior portion. The は is rather unnecessary in this context, and is only just a common communicative thing to do.

Doesn't the OP just want to know if the sentence 「そのために、たくさんの努力が必要です。」would be valid and mean the same thing? Is there a reason you didn't address that?

Uh...I will edit my response.
